# php force download xml

Tags: php, xml, download

I am creating an xml file on the fly. When a user generates this file I want it to open up a download file dialog with the content that was generated. There is no actual file because it is just generated through php. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Send a [content-disposition attachment](https://web.archive.org/web/20070410125924/http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/forcedownload.html) header.

Comment: You obviously didnt read my post. There is no actual file to read. It is just sent to the page and I do not want to create a file just be able to download what it generates.

Comment: @ngreen you obviously didn't read the linked article. set the said header and echo out the xml data.

Comment: oh nice I thought you actually had to assign it that file...thanks for the info

Comment: This link sends to a Loan company, nothing to do with the question. No idea how it has been redirected on that...

Comment: @No_or_yes — Domains expire and get bought by other people. I've replaced the link with one to an archive.

Answer (score 15):

This is what worked for me. In `readfile('newfile.xml');` make sure to give the path of the file correctly. This php page is called from an html page with anchor tag which says - download:

```
<?php 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="newfile.xml"');
header('Content-type: "text/xml"; charset="utf8"');
readfile('newfile.xml');
?>
```

source: [How do I force the browser to download a file to disk instead of playing or displaying it?](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/forcedownload.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=advertise.xml');
header ("Content-Type:text/xml"); 
//output the XML data
echo  $xml;
 // if you want to directly download then set expires time
header("Expires: 0");
```

Comment: please also add some description for user understanding