# Generated xml file is harmful for computer?

Tags: php, xml, header, http-headers, header-files

I did an xml file and force download it by these headers:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="export.xml"');
header('Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf8');
readfile('export.xml');
```

But before the download I see a dialog that this file can be harmful for my computer? How to get rid of this dialog? Maybe my headers is wrong?

**upd** Well, can do nothing, I did a test on my test-hosting, u can check it here: [site with generation link](http://wpxchange.host56.com), and an xml file as is: [export.xml](http://wpxchange.host56.com/export.xml)

Comment: Does your browser show the same message for all files that are to be downloaded?

Comment: nope, just it, also I can open him without any risk through the real url in browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php force download xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696500/php-force-download-xml)

Comment: I took a headers from it. But there is no words about a harmful dialog.

Comment: seems I need a whitelist of chrome's downaloadable files with risk.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `application/xml` to `text/xml`.  Probably your browser thinks that `application` means executable.

Comment: actually it was before, I thought that the browser doesn't like the `text/xml` header, no difference, still this dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="export.xml"');
header('Content-type: "text/xml"; charset="utf8"');
readfile('export.xml');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***Note:** This does not solve your issue, however it did solve an issue I had on my computer giving that notice (windows, chrome, apache webserver, PHP 5.4.10). I leave it here for future visitors.*

Some browsers do not only look for the headers but also for the "filename" in the URL.

For example if you download a PHP file that *contains* XML, the browser might identify it as a dangerous file (because it can be executed on your system or is not within some whitelist or what not):

```
http://example.com/xml-download.php
```

A simple solution is to make this file not end with `.php` any longer, for example by adding a `?`:

```
http://example.com/xml-download.php?
```

And continue with that to even signal the filename that way:

```
http://example.com/xml-download.php?export.xml
```

(the last one is not necessary but can be useful especially with some older browsers)

Comment: I dont know, but maybe this could be the answer: https://codereview.chromium.org/3899002/diff/5001/chrome/browser/download/download_exe.cc

Comment: though, watch in bottom: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/download/download_exe.cc?view=markup&pathrev=63158