# Add Data To A XML File Using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I would like to add some data to a XML file using PHP. I'm quite new and so do not know much of the terminology and so will try to explain it as much as possible.
Thanks
Joe

XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<music>
    <song>
        <title>Example Song</title>
        <album>A Album</album>
        <artist>A Artist</artist>
        <length>3.41</length>
    </song>
//The New Song I Would Like To Add For Example
    <song>
        <title>Another Example Song</title>
        <album>Another A Album</album>
        <artist>Another A Artist</artist>
        <length>Another 3.41</length>
    </song>
//The End Of The New Song I Would Like To Add

</music>
```

Comment: I think that [How to generate XML file dynamically using PHP?][1] maybe helps you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/487282/5127395

Comment: Thanks but it does not seem to save or add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested that but I think that it would be work

With SimpleXML

```
// Read file    
$music = simplexml_load_file('music.xml');

$character = $music->addChild('song');
$character->addChild('title', 'Another Example Song');
$character->addChild('album', 'Another A Album');
$character->addChild('artist', 'Another A Artist');
$character->addChild('length', 'Another 3.41');
```

And then [force download the new file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141721/5127395)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$xml_load = simplexml_load_file($Your_xml);
$song = $xml_load->addChild("song");
$song->addChild("title", "song title");
$song->addChild("album", "song album");
$song->addChild("artist", "song artist");
$song->addChild("length", "03:01");

echo $xml_load->saveXML()
```

Comment: Hello Thanks but this does not seem to save it is there any way of doing this or is it just me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP's [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

[The SimpleXML usage page](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) gives a good tutorial of how to use it.